Simple counterexample for if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ then $f$ is monotonic
If $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty,$$ then we can't conclude that there exists an $M$ where $f$ is monotonic on $[M,\infty)$ because $f(x)=\ln x+\sin x$ disproves that claim. What I want to know is, if my example is the "standard" counterexample, or maybe there is a more "simple" counterexample.

Perhaps you'd consider $x + 2\sin x$ a little simpler. One fewer transcendental function.

You could take $f(x)=2\lfloor x\rfloor - x$

Oh yeah! Define $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x-1 \quad &\text{if $x$ is an integer}\\
x \quad &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
